# const pointer to const inside srtuct in function prototype

Tags: c, pointers, struct, constants

I have the following struct:

```
struct foo
{
    ...
    char* cp;
};
```

And I want to pass a `struct foo` type pointer to a function, but I want the function to cast the pointer to `const char* const cp`, and I don't want the `const` qualifier as part of the definition of `struct foo`. Declaring the function as:

```
void func (const struct foo* foo_i);
```

will ensure the pointer `cp` is unchanged, but not the data it points to. Is there a way to declare the function so that the data is ensured to be read-only too?

Comment: So you want red car to be taken as a blue car without painting it?

Comment: That's simply not possible. Other than making `cp` a pointer to `const char`.

Comment: And can you please elaborate on *why* you want this? What is the *real* problem you want to solve? Please [read about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and think about if this question (in its current form) might be one?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't think my question falls in the XY category. Obviously there are good reasons why a pointer to a `const` should be accepted by a function to ensure the data can't change. There are tons of functions which accept such a `const` pointer, or `const` array of `const`, where `const` is not part of the type definitions (e.g. look at `aio_suspend`). I simply ask how to declare the function when the pointer is inside a `struct`

Comment: @alk, adding a `const` qualifier does not change the type, how is this a red vs blue car issue?

Comment: @AaylaSecura.: If I am not misunderstanding -  you want to make what `cp` points to `const` without using the `const` keyword with it explicitly?

Comment: @coderrdoc Yes, without defining the type `struct foo` to contain `const char* cp;`. Correct me if I'm wrong, the `const` would then apply to any instance of a `struct foo`, which is not desirable. I merely want to ensure the instance that the function works with will be such. Am I misunderstanding the role of `const`?

Comment: Would it be an option to use a different `struct` in the declaration of the function's parameters?

Comment: @alk, I could declare an otherwise identical struct, but with a const pointer and accept either of the two (with an implicit cast), but it looks not right... Another workaround is to remove the pointer from the struct definition and pass it as a separate argument, but this is impractical, especially if lots of code depends on the function.

Comment: @AaylaSecura.: Using `const` doesn't mean that what `cp` points to will come under the same rule. By that we mean - we can't change `cp` to point to another `char` but we can change the content of what `cp` points to without violating any `const` constraint applied over the instace of `struct foo`.

Comment: @coderredoc, You can apply a `const` qualifier to the pointer itself, or to the data. What you're talking about is `char* const cp`, which would be the result if the function prototype has `const struct* foo foo_i`. What I want is `const char* cp`, which means the data `cp` points to cannot be changed (through that pointer).

Comment: @AaylaSecura.: Yes I get it. I was talking about the constraint applied over `cp` due to `const struct foo * foo_i`. How would what you said is possible without using the `const` on `cp` itself?

Comment: @coderredoc, are you saying that if I want a pointer member of a struct to point to a `const` type, this MUST always be in the definition of the struct itself?

Comment: @AaylaSecura: I'd say so, yes. Where else?

Comment: @AaylaSecura.: I am afraid the answer is yes...not sure why you have this issue though

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I was misunderstanding the role of `const`. That settles it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is *not* possible.

Consider making `cp` of type `const char*`.